# Safari offers to translate all web pages -- how to limit to languages I actually do not speak?

Tags: safari, internationalization

In macOS 11.1 "Big Sur", Safari gained the capability of offering translations of web pages. Google's Chrome has a similar feature, and offers to select a set of languages that the user actually understands so that translations are only offered for other, unknown languages.

Is there a way to tell Safari's new translation feature "I already speak German, English, French and Italian so don't offer translations for web pages in those languages"?

Comment: Have you added those languages to your language list in System Preferences? I believe this tells it what languages to offer translation to, so it'll probably avoid offering translation from them as well.

Comment: I did, and still get the notifications for all but my primary language.